# What is the history behind the ~ in subdomains/university hosting for studuents?

Tags: website, hosting, subdomain

What is the history behind the ~ in subdomains/university hosting for students? Why not subdomain.site.edu or site.edu/subdomain. Any particular reason the ~ was chosen and not something else?

Comment: Do you mean `www.site.edu/~username`? If so, that's a Unix question, nothing really to do with universities, - and there are plenty of people who'll be able to give a much better response than me

Comment: Its just *nix thing not really a matter for University. In unix ~ is a shorthand for home directory. ~username means the home folder for that user.

Comment: As providing domain name for everyone is not possible or out of scope. They provide the user with their home folder with web accessible address like this.

Answer (score 6):

`~` is usually short-hand for the user's home folder. Many HTTP web servers will interpret that as the user's home folder, then their `public_html` (or equivalent) folder, and serve up the page from there. This would allow companies to allow many people to host their own "sites" off their main site, without the need of extra permissions

Answer (score 3):

Historical reasons:
In unix the tilde (`~`) refers to your home directory.

For files already on your computer:
`~`: Your home.
`~someuser`: The homedirctory of *someuser*.

It simply makes sense if you look at it like this:
http://university_domain.edu/       -> General homepage of the server
http://university_domain.edu/~user -> webpage of *user* on that server